# How do I get a notification sound on my iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, notifications

For apps like Instagram or Snapchat, when my screen is on the lock screen and a notification shows up, there is no sound.  Can I enable notification sounds for Instagram or Snapchat?

Comment: In the settings app - have you perhaps turned off sound for Instagram in notifications? If so, and a notification arrives and is silent, then it's up to the programmer to add a sound to their app and not so much that you would tell the OS to play this sound for that app.

Comment: Is the silent switch on the side of the iPhone activated (orange)?

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Settings > Notification Center > Snapchat > Toggle Sound

### Method 2

Snapchat > Settings Button > Notifications > Toggle it